# Сокращение запроса get

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Такой вот запрос,

```
$month = $_GET['month'];
$day = $_GET['day'];
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM client WHERE month = "'.$month.'" and day = "'.$day.'"') or die (mysql_error()); 
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
print"<br><b>Результат:</b> <a href=../index.php?option=content&task=view&id=".$r['url'].">".$r['name']."</a>";
}
```

Результат, думаю, Вам понятен. `client.php?month=1&day=22` выводит имена клиентов за январь месяц 22 число. А как сделать так, чтоб работала ссылка `client.php?month=1`, чтоб выводились все клиенты за январь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подготавливайте запрос в зависимости от того, прищла ли переменная **$_GET['day']** или нет:

```
$month = (int)$_GET['month'];
$day = (int)$_GET['day'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE month = '$month'";
if($day != 0){
    $query .= " AND day = '$day'";
}
// Выполняем запрос
$sql = mysql_query($query);
// и так далее ...
```